# Getting 0 for my non closed a non closed line integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

I am trying to find the line integral of the field: $F = (3y- \frac{y}{x^2}e^{1/x},sin(y)+ e^{1/x})$ for the line:
$$C: x=t,y=0,-6\leq t \leq -2$$
So I used the formula and got to find:

$$\int^{-6}_{-2} (3\cdot 0 - \frac{0}{t^2}\cdot e^{1/t})\cdot x'(t)\cdot dt = 0$$
I checked my result many times for mistakes but couldn't find any . Also checked the internet for similar situations but didn't find any explanation for that... 
Is my caclualtion wrong? and if it isn't, how is it possible to get a 0 result for non closed line?

Comment: I think the OP's calculation is right. It is possible to get a 0 result for non closed line.

Comment: @AndreasBlass no, but y'(t) = 0, as y(t) = 0 so this part of the field will be 0 anyway inside the integration.

Comment: @AndreasBlass If $F = (f,g)$ , then $f = 3y−frac{y}{x^2 }\cdot e1/x$. $C:x=t,y=0,−6≤t≤−2$
So $\int_{c} f dx= \int ^{-6}_{-2}f(x(t),y(t)) \cdot x'(t)$ and the rest is up there ^

Comment: OK. Although you seem to be using $f$ for two different things, I think  I now see what you were doing, so I'll delete my previous comments. The line integral is indeed zero.

Comment: Why shouldn't you be able to get zero?  What if the integrand were identically $0$.  In this case, the integral reduces to an ordinary real definite integral.  Obviously, that can be $0$, even if the integrand is not identically $0$.  Yes, there's an important special case, where the integral over a closed loop is zero, but that doesn't mean no other integrals can be zero.